# Loop - If one from several conditions is True append to new list

Tags: python, loops, append

I'm writing some code:

```
for b in result:
    #if re.match('[V]\W\d\W\D+\.*\D+\W\d+\W+', b) not in str(b):
    if 'FillLevel[' not in str(b):
        new_list.append(b)
    #elif 'CycleMAX[' not in str(b):
    #    new_list.append(b)
    #elif 'CycleMIN[' not in str(b):
    #    new_list.append(b)
    #elif 'CycleAvg[' not in str(b):
    #    new_list.append(b)
```

And their work only when i have one condition (if).
How to change this code to work with few condition ?
result is an array, for example `result[5] == ['V', '4', 'FillLevel[64]', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'INT126", '2', 'CPUA.DB1610.126,I;RW', 'RW', '0', "0']"]`

Comment: Have you tried `if any(item not in str(b) for item in ('FillLevel[', 'CycleMAX['...)): new_list.append(b)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you actually intend to do? Your example code would filter out only the lists that contain all of the words 'FillLevel[', 'CycleMAX[', 'CycleMIN[', etc. altogether. So only lists like this would get removed: `['V', '4', 'FillLevel[64]', 'CycleMAX[', 'CycleMIN[', ...]`.

TigerhawkT3's code works correctly if that's what you want.

For linusg's first example you'd have to add a `break` after the `new_list.append(b)` line, otherwise it appends the same lists several times.

---

Did you maybe intend to remove all the lists that contain any of these words not all? Then try something like this (similar to the other answers):

```
words = ('FillLevel[', 'CycleMAX[', 'CycleMIN[')  # etc.

for b in results:
    if not any(word in str(b) for word in words):
        new_list.append(b)
```

Or:

```
for b in results:
    for word in words:
       if word in str(b):
           break
    else:  # This else clause is executed only if no break occurs.
        new_list.append(b)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [b for b in results if not any(word in str(b) for word in words)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
for b in result:
    for entry in ['FillLevel[', 'CycleMAX[', ...]:
        if entry not in str(b):
            new_list.append(b)
```

Or, if @TigerhawkT3 has commented, the more shorter, pythonic and unreadable way would be:

```
for b in result:
    if any(item not in str(b) for item in ('FillLevel[', 'CycleMAX[', ...)): 
        new_list.append(b)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work. First example works also only with one argument.
And second example doesn't work :(

Comment: Isn't possible. Something in your other code must be wrong

Comment: In this case:
            `for entry in ['FillLevel[', 'CycleMAX[']:
                if entry not in str(b):
                    new_list.append(b)`
Each line is twice (except where is string 'FillLevel[' or 'CycleMAX[' - they line are only once)
And I want to have each line (only once) where not find define strings.

Comment: Maybe will be better make this with regex ? Fox example, how to use regex example from my question (`'[V]\W\d\W\D+\.*\D+\W\d+\W+'`) to my code ?